# how to use the tee to output rtmp and one stdout for ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg, tee

i want to output ffmpeg to one rtmp stream.
and at the same time, I want to handle the H264 stream by my program.
I already tried "ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Webcam C110" -vcodec libx264 -f tee -map 0:v "xx.mkv|-"

but not work.

Answer (score 2):

Base syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Webcam C110" -vcodec libx264 -f tee -map 0:v "[f=flv]rtmp://url|[f=h264]pipe:1"
```